# Parser error in mvc3 razor code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, nerddinner

I'm getting this error in my cshtml file   near this code

```
@{      
    var options = new OpenIdSelector();
    options.TextBox.LogOnText = "Log On";
}
```

Parser Error

> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unexpected "{" after "@" character. Once inside the body of a code block (@if {}, @{}, etc.) you do not need to use "@{" to switch to code.

---

```
@using DotNetOpenAuth.Mvc
@using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty
@{ 
 ViewBag.Title = "Log On"; 
}
<div id="login-oauth">
        <h3>via 3rd Party (recommended)</h3>
        
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("LogOnContent");}


    </div>
    <div id="or">OR</div>
    <div id="login-account">
        <h3>using a account</h3>
         </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div>
            <p>
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                @(Html.TextBox("username"))
                @(Html.ValidationMessage("username", "*"))
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                @(Html.Password("password"))
                @(Html.ValidationMessage("password", "*"))
            </p>
            <p>
                @(Html.CheckBox("rememberMe")) <label class="inline" for="rememberMe">Remember me?</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input class="classiclogon" type="submit" value="Log On" />
            </p>
            <p>
                Please enter your username and password. @(Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register")) if you don't have an account.
            </p>
        </div>
   
    
        
 @{     
     {
            var options = new OpenIdSelector();
            options.TextBox.LogOnText = "Log On";
}
        }
       @MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.OpenIdSelectorScripts(options, null))
   @* @(Html.OpenIdSelectorScripts(this.Page, options, null))*@
    
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you're already in a code block not a mark-up block. What does the surrounding code look like? Does it work if you drop the `@{` and `}`?

Comment: Show us the surroundings please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're already in the

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
```

block, so your

```
var options = new OpenIdSelector();
options.TextBox.LogOnText = "Log On";
```

block does not have to begin with `@{`. Pretty much what the error says.

You can also just move those two lines to the code block at the top, where you set `ViewBag.Title`, to keep your HTML free from code as much as possible.